# Acquiring Dutch citizenship

Tags: citizenship

I was born in the Netherlands in 1965.  2 years later, my parents decided to immigrate to South Africa.  I automatically became a SA Citizen, I never really applied for SA Citizen ship.  Would I be able to now apply for Dutch citizenship and obtain a Dutch passport but still live in SA?

Comment: At what age and through what legal mechanism did you become a South African citizen?

Comment: I have no idea.  2 of my sibs applied for SA citizenship as well as my dad.  My mom only applied for citizenship in 1995 to enable her to vote.  When I applied for my ID (I think at the age of 16) it was indicated on my ID book "Born in Netherlands but SA Citizen".  I automatically became a citizen.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is important to find out how you became a citizen.  It seems likely that you acquired citizenship automatically when your father naturalized.  Do you know when he naturalized?  How old were you and your siblings at that point (the difference in age could explain why they had to apply separately)?